# Mapping multiple values into a column

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the below table.

How can I map multiple tags that are on one row and turn that into the tag description? There are thousands of combinations.

Table: TAG_SEARCH

```
DATE        ID     TAGS
6/25/2019   101    1251:1306
6/25/2019   102    1251
6/25/2019   103    1251:1306:1274:1446:1452:1586
6/25/2019   104    1251:1306:1586
```

Table TAG_MAP

```
TAG_TYPE    TAG_DESC
  1251        Clothing
  1306        Grocery
  1274        Hardware
  1446        Home_Decor
  1452        Electric
  1586        Plumbing
```

Expected Results:

```
DATE       ID   TAGS
6/25/2019  101   Clothing:Grocery
6/25/2019  102   Clothing
6/25/2019  103   Clothing:Grocery:Hardware:Home_Decor:Electric:Plumbing
6/25/2019  104   Clothing:Grocery:Plumbing
```

Comment: That's a horrible design to begin with. Do you have any chance to properly normalize that?

Comment: That's the results that was give to me but yeah I think there's opportunity to revisit the design.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic - although the answer is technically possible, but it would promote antipatterns and bad design.

Comment: I've seen worse... sometimes you have to work with what you have... but if the design can change... no need to try to solve this question... If you are stuck with this design however... It can certainly be done.

Comment: Please don't close the question. If a redesign is possible that would take months to prioritize the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider how to do this in a normalized fashion so that the data is searchable and summable and, basically, useful.

Let's assume you're stuck with your first two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TAG_SEARCH
  (TAG_DT         DATE,
   TAG_ID         NUMBER,
   TAGS           VARCHAR2(4000));

CREATE TABLE TAG_MAP
  (TAG_TYPE       NUMBER,
   TAG_DESC       VARCHAR2(100));
```

and you're looking to store your data in an output table:

```
CREATE TABLE TAGS_OUT
  (TAG_DT         DATE,
   TAG_ID         NUMBER,
   TAG_DESC       VARCHAR2(100));
```

Now, if we populate our tables as

```
MERGE INTO TAG_SEARCH ts
  USING (SELECT TO_DATE('6/25/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS TAG_DT, 101 AS TAG_ID, '1251:1306' AS TAGS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_DATE('6/25/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS TAG_DT, 102 AS TAG_ID, '1251' AS TAGS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_DATE('6/25/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS TAG_DT, 103 AS TAG_ID, '1251:1306:1274:1446:1452:1586' AS TAGS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_DATE('6/25/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS TAG_DT, 104 AS TAG_ID, '1251:1306:1586' AS TAGS FROM DUAL) d
    ON (d.TAG_ID = ts.TAG_ID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (TAG_DT, TAG_ID, TAGS) VALUES (d.TAG_DT, d.TAG_ID, d.TAGS);
```

and

```
MERGE INTO TAG_MAP tm
  USING (SELECT 1251 AS TAG_TYPE, 'Clothing' AS TAG_DESC FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 1306 AS TAG_TYPE, 'Grocery' AS TAG_DESC FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 1274 AS TAG_TYPE, 'Hardware' AS TAG_DESC FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 1446 AS TAG_TYPE, 'Home_Decor' AS TAG_DESC FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 1452 AS TAG_TYPE, 'Electric' AS TAG_DESC FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 1586 AS TAG_TYPE, 'Plumbing' AS TAG_DESC FROM DUAL) d
    ON (d.TAG_TYPE = tm.TAG_TYPE)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (TAG_TYPE, TAG_DESC) VALUES (d.TAG_TYPE, d.TAG_DESC);
```

we can abuse a hierarchical query a bit to get it to spit out the individual tags:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TAG_ID, LEVEL, TAG_DT, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TAGS,'[^:]+', 1, LEVEL) AS TAG_TYPE
  FROM TAG_SEARCH
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(TAGS,'[^:]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY TAG_ID, LEVEL
```

and once we're there changing the TAG_TYPE to TAG_DESC is a simple matter of joining in the TAG_MAP table appropriately:

```
SELECT q.TAG_ID, q.LVL, q.TAG_DT, tm.TAG_DESC
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TAG_ID, LEVEL AS LVL, TAG_DT, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TAGS,'[^:]+', 1, LEVEL) AS TAG_TYPE
          FROM TAG_SEARCH
          CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(TAGS,'[^:]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
          ORDER BY TAG_ID, LEVEL) q
  INNER JOIN TAG_MAP tm
    ON tm.TAG_TYPE = q.TAG_TYPE
  ORDER BY q.TAG_ID, q.LVL
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7406861844da5c3c5e9164cb3a46acd0)

Comment: Thanks! You think there's an oracle hint that can be utilized here to make the full query results return faster?

Comment: A hint is literally the *last* thing you should consider when you have a performance problem. The first thing to do is to look at the query plan and determine what actions to take - most likely adding the appropriate indexes to tables which are being searched using a FULL TABLE SCAN. I suggest you try that and, if that doesn't help, ask a question about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Agree that the design is anti-relational. This is just to show that SQL can do it. Warning: LISTAGG requires database version 11.2 or later.

UPDATE: I forgot that the order of tag descriptions should match the order of the tag types in the source table. This solution does not respect that order. The regexp_substr answer does.

```
create table tAG_SEARCH(DTE,ID,TAGS) as
select to_date('6/25/2019','mm/dd/yyyy'),   101,    '1251:1306' from dual union all
select to_date('6/25/2019','mm/dd/yyyy'),   102,    '1251' from dual union all
select to_date('6/25/2019','mm/dd/yyyy'),   103,    '1251:1306:1274:1446:1452:1586' from dual union all
select to_date('6/25/2019','mm/dd/yyyy'),   104,    '1251:1306:1586' from dual;

create Table TAG_MAP(TAG_TYPE,TAG_DESC) as
select  1251,'Clothing' from dual union all
select  1306,'Grocery' from dual union all
select  1274,'Hardware' from dual union all
select  1446,'Home_Decor' from dual union all
select  1452,'Electric' from dual union all
select  1586,'Plumbing' from dual;

select dte, id,
  listagg(tag_desc, ':') within group(order by tag_type) tags
from tag_search ts 
join tag_map tm on instr(tags, tag_type) > 0
group by dte, id
order by dte, id;

DTE         ID   TAGS                                                     
2019-06-25  101  Clothing:Grocery                                          
2019-06-25  102  Clothing                                                  
2019-06-25  103  Clothing:Hardware:Grocery:Home_Decor:Electric:Plumbing    
2019-06-25  104  Clothing:Grocery:Plumbing
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_substr()` window analytic function to split for the first step, and then `listagg()` function to concatenate the explanations in the look-up table(`tag_map`)

```
with tag_search( "Date", id, tags ) as
(
 select date'2019-06-25',101,'1251:1306'                     from dual union all
 select date'2019-06-25',102,'1251'                          from dual union all
 select date'2019-06-25',103,'1251:1306:1274:1446:1452:1586' from dual union all
 select date'2019-06-25',104,'1251:1306:1586'                from dual
), tag_map( tag_type, tag_desc) as
(
 select 1251, 'Clothing'   from dual union all
 select 1306, 'Grocery'    from dual union all
 select 1274, 'Hardware'   from dual union all
 select 1446, 'Home_Decor' from dual union all
 select 1452, 'Electric'   from dual union all
 select 1586, 'Plumbing'   from dual
), t as
(
select "Date", id, regexp_substr(tags,'[^:]+',1,level) as tags,
       row_number() over (order by id, level) as lvl
  from tag_search
 connect by level <= regexp_count(tags,':') + 1
    and prior id = id
    and prior sys_guid() is not null
)
select "Date", id, listagg(tag_desc,':') within group (order by id, lvl) as tags   
  from t
  join tag_map on tag_type = tags
 group by "Date", id;

 Date       ID  TAGS
 ---------  --- -------------------------------------------------------
 25-JUN-19  101 Clothing:Grocery
 25-JUN-19  102 Clothing
 25-JUN-19  103 Clothing:Grocery:Hardware:Home_Decor:Electric:Plumbing
 25-JUN-19  104 Clothing:Grocery:Plumbing
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d23069cb907fc5711f2c72ec45ddb957)</kbd>